# UITableview with 2 Sections Selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My UITableview has 2 Sections each section has number of rows, I want to allow multiple selection in tableview but each section should only 1 row.

In other words "I want to allow 2 selection in entire tableview & 1 selection in each section"

Anyone could help will be grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)` to allow or not a selection according if another one is already selected in the same section, or deselect the previous one in the section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same with custom implementation as below

> Define 2 element array to hold the uniq selection for per section

```
var selection = [-1, -1]
```

> Custom methods to handle user selection

```
func setSelection(for index: IndexPath) {
    if selection[index.section] != -1 {
      //clear the old selection
      let cell = getCell(for: IndexPath(row: selection[index.section], section: index.section))
      cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    //add new selectoin
    let currCell = getCell(for: index)
    currCell.backgroundColor = .orange

    //save new selection state
    selection[index.section] = index.row
  }

func getCell(for index: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = custTableView.cellForRow(at: index)
    return cell!
  }
```

`setSelection` needs to get called from `didSelectRowAt` as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    setSelection(for: indexPath)
  }
```

You can also use the `selection` array anytime to know the selected cell indexes

**Output:**

> [image]